# How to avoid duplicating Object if I want to parse it in 2 different JSON

Tags: json, parsing, go

I have an object that I receive:

```
{
    "operation": "ACC00000001", 
    "prm": "23597250350000", 
    "conso_prod": "Conso",
    "index_name": "BASE",
    "index_value": "123456",
    "timestamp": "2019-08-20T22:00:00Z"
 }
```

The object I use is in a common lib, so it is shared by several services:

common.Measure:

```
type Measure struct {
    Timestamp     time.Time
    Delta         float64
    Redistributed float64
    IsProd        bool
    IndexValue    uint32
    IndexName     string 
    Source        string 
}
```

and Meter:

```
type Meter struct {
    ID          string
    Operation string
    Unit        string
    Timestep    time.Duration
    Measures    []Measure
}
```

But as the labels don't match, I must create another object  `MeasureFromJSON` which is the created based in the json I receive.

```
type MeasureFromJSON struct {
    Operation   string `json:"operation" binding:"required"`
    Prm         string `json:"prm"`
    Conso_prod  string `json:"conso_prod"`
    Index_name  string `json:"index_name"`
    Index_value string `json:"index_value"`
    Timestamp   string `json:"timestamp"`
}
```

Thing is I don't like to use 2 models for the same entity, just because I have no JSON labels in common object. Is there a way to use the common models (`meter.Measure`)?

Comment: Have you tried `IndexName string \`json:"index_name"\``? Or what exactly do you mean by "labels don't match"?

Comment: Why don't you add `json` tags to `Measure` in `common`? Then problem would be solved, or do I miss something?

Comment: how come the same entity return 2 different models?

Comment: @icza but then, I won't be able to have different parsing for the same objects, will I ?

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro I don't understand what you mean by different parsing, can you show concrete examples?

Comment: Differents labels. In one case, I will have prm label :  Prm         string `json:"prm"`, and on the other case, I will receive PRM label:  Prm         string `json:"prmID"`. Thing is I don't always decide the name of the fields, my providers do.

Comment: If you have two different json objects you need two different Go structs (or use a map), Go does not support changing tags at runtime. A solution to avoid duplication would be more complicated than the duplication itself.

Answer (score 0):

> Thing is I don't like to use 2 models for the same entity, just because I have no JSON labels in common object

First of all, I have a question, how come same entity return two different sets of data that majority of the fields are different?

If those different fields are still from single entity, then you could probably combine the fields and store it into single `common.Measure`.

```golang
type Measure struct {
    Timestamp     time.Time `json:"timestamp"`
    Delta         float64
    Redistributed float64
    IsProd        bool
    IndexValue    string `json:"index_value"`
    IndexName     string `json:"index_name"` 
    Source        string 
    ConsoProd     string  `json:"conso_prod"` 
    Prm           string  `json:"prm"` 
    Operation     string  `json:"operation"` 
}
```

Comment: But how should I do it if I need 2 different parsing for the same object ? I will change my fields so it match. But if in common, I add json parsing, I will not be able to change label for another service, If I need to receive labels with another name.

Comment: then why not go with two structs like what you already do now